# Google Analytics setting up across domain tracking

Tags: javascript, html, google-analytics

I'm trying to set up cross domain tracking using google analytics. Basically I have a widget which directs customers to a shopping basket where they can purchase an item.

We need to give the client some code to put on their receipt page but i am having trouble setting it up.  I have set up a dummy project on two domains with the following code on our main page (which will be the widget when developed) that has the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title> 
<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-27715734-3']);
  _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'myDomainA.com']);
  _gaq.push(['_setAllowLinker', true]);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>


</head>
<body>


     <p>Direct to techport page &nbsp; <a href ="http://techport.e-talemarketing.co/Payment.html"onclick="_gaq.push(['_link', 'http://techport.e-talemarketing.co/Payment.html']); return false;"><input id="btnTechport" type="button" value="techport" /></a></p>

     <p>Direct to forOffice page &nbsp; <a href ="http://foroffice.etailtesting.co.uk/Payment.html"onclick="_gaq.push(['_link', 'http://foroffice.etailtesting.co.uk/Payment.html']); return false;"><input id="btnForOffice" type="button" value="ForOffice" /></a></p>
```

and have put the following on the dummy receipt page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-27715734-3']);
  _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'myDomainA.com']);
  _gaq.push(['_setAllowLinker', true]);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

     // add item might be called for every item in the shopping cart
        // where your ecommerce engine loops through each item in the cart and
        // prints out _addItem for each
        _gaq.push(['_addItem',
                        'techport222',           // order ID - required
                        '54321',                    // SKU/code - required
                        'Shiny jewels',          // product name
                        '',                             // category or variation
                        '8',                           // unit price - required
                        '3'    

                         ]);

        _gaq.push(['_trackTrans']); //confirms that a purchase has occurred and submits transaction to the Analytics servers

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>



</head>
<body>
    <p>
       TechPort Payment receipt for item</p>
</body>
</html>
```

When setting up my account in Google Analytics i have made the default URL the main page url so www.MyDomainA.com.

And added 2 different shopping baskets.

I cannot see any events being tracked can anyone see what i am doing wrong?

I have set E-commerce tracking to true on both profiles aswel.

Edit: There is a strong possibility i was just being impatient as i can see events now - i just thought that the event section of google analytic s was meant to be real time...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How long have you given it?  Sometimes it takes a few days to see events when they are fist setup.  In your case, it looks like you are missing the `_addTrans` method at the start of your ecommerce tracking.

```
 _gaq.push(['_addTrans',      
      '1234',           // order ID - required
      'Womens Apparel', // affiliation or store name
      '28.28',          // total - required
      '1.29',           // tax
      '15.00',          // shipping
      'San Jose',       // city
      'California',     // state or province
      'USA'             // country
   ]);
   ...
   _gaq.push(['_addItem',...

   ...
   _gaq.push(['_trackTrans',...
```

Documentation here - http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gaJS/gaJSApiEcommerce.html#_gat.GA_Tracker_._addTrans

Comment: i have only been putting them through today and as some are coming through it may be ok thanks for the advice on the addTrans i ll add that to see if i get anything extra thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help. `addTrans` is not optional, it is required for GA Ecommerce to work.